# Migrating windows partition of a dual boot to an ssd

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

Let me describe my storage.

1. One HDD of 1To (/dev/sda)
2. one hold SSD of 64 Go  (/dev/sdc)
3. A new SSD of 465 Go (/dev/sdb)

These are the partitions of my hdd (/dev/sda) :
[image]

I have Three systems :

- A windows 10 on the HDD (including a  reserved for the partition system) on sda1 and sda2. This is the orignial drive with windows on it.
- A linux mint on sda3 so the hdd is in dual boot.
- A debian with the root file system on the hold SSd (/sdc) and the home on the HDD (/dev/sda5) 
  What I would like to do is  to move the windows partition to the new ssd. 
  But I  am not sure how to proceed. I tried with clonezilla but when I cloned only the windows partition /dev/sda2 on /dev/sdb, neither grub nor windows could see a bootable disk.

Any help would be appreciated !